# Error When Restoring Backed Up Tables

Tags: mysql, restore

I followed directions from this page: https://serverfault.com/questions/271367/importing-data-from-myd-back-up-file

I dropped the 3 files ( t2010_08.frm, t2010_08.myd, t2010_08.myi ) into my /var/lib/mysql directory.

Then I changed permission with the "chown mysql:mysql t2010_08.* command". Now, when I go to look at my table ( in HeidiSQL ), it tells me that it is type "View" and I get "Can't find file: 't2010_08' (errno:2) message.

What do I still need to do to gain access to this table?

Comment: What exact folder did you put the `t2010` table?

Comment: into a database named bsgtran... so path was /var/lib/mysql/bsgtran, there are other tables there that I can see. I have also changed permissions on the table to 660, but still get the same error message. "ERROR 1017 (HY000): Can't find file: 't2010_08' (errno: 2)"

Comment: I have now also restarted MySQL to no effect.

Comment: Was the folder bsgtran already in existence before you decided to you t2010_08.* in it?

Comment: Never mind, you answered that in previous comment.

Comment: A view is defined in information_schema.tables is a table entry whose engine is NULL. Please run `USE bsgtran;` followed by `SHOW TABLES;`. Does `bsgtran` show up as a table?

Comment: No bsgtran is the database. There is no table with that name.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4317/discussion-between-rolandomysqldba-and-dba-noob)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it.

Here is the table as it appears in Linux from the Chat Session

```
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql 9478 Jul 30 07:18 /var/lib/mysql/bsgtran/t2010_08.frm 
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql 1882892084 Jul 30 07:21 /var/lib/mysql/bsgtran/t2010_08.myd 
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql 74588160 Jul 30 07:22 /var/lib/mysql/bsgtran/t2010_08.myi
```

Since the database is on a Linux OS, filenames are case-sensitive.

Here is the solution

```
mv /var/lib/mysql/bsgtran/t2010_08.myd /var/lib/mysql/bsgtran/t2010_08.MYD
mv /var/lib/mysql/bsgtran/t2010_08.myi /var/lib/mysql/bsgtran/t2010_08.MYI
```

File extensions must be uppercase for MyISAM tables in Linux

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Yes, it worked!!! Thank you Thank you Thank you!!!