# Migrating MySQL from Windows to Linux

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.6, myisam, mysql-5.7

I'm new to MySQL.  However I am very familiar with Oracle and MSSQL.  This is what I have done so far:

1. Installed MySQL 5.7 on RHEL 7.2
2. Created a test db called "mydb" and test table called "employee".
3. Location of these files are 
   /usr/var/lib/mydb
   /usr/var/lib/mydb/employee.frm
   /usr/var/lib/mydb/employee.idb
4. Able to connect to MySQL from a client machine and can see the "mydb".

So my server and connectivity are fine.  Now I want to move some of the MySQL 5.0 databases from an old Windows box to this new RHEL Linux box.

Sample of old MySQL 5.0 database files:

5. region.myd
   region.myi
   region.frm

I don't have much knowledge of the MySQL database architecture.  I just noticed the MySQL 5.0 has extensions of .frm, .myd and myi while the MySQL 5.7 has .frm and the .ibd

My question is: How can I quickly migrate those two "region" files to my new RHEL box so they conform to the .frm and .ibd file format?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

***OK Brace yourself***. You can migrate the table from Windows by copying it and converting it.

STEP 01

Copy those three(3) files into the data folder `/usr/var/lib/mydb` in Linux

You should have

- `/usr/var/lib/mydb/region.frm`
- `/usr/var/lib/mydb/region.myd`
- `/usr/var/lib/mydb/region.myi`

STEP 02

Change the filename name extensions of two of the files

```
cd /usr/var/lib/mydb
mv region.myd region.MYD
mv region.myi region.MYI
```

Required for MyISAM tables in Linux

- See my old post [Error When Restoring Backed Up Tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21677/error-when-restoring-backed-up-tables/21712#21712)
- See the [chat session that I used to troubleshoot this question](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4317/discussion-between-rolandomysqldba-and-dba-noob)

STEP 03

Change the owner of the three files

```
cd /usr/var/lib/mydb
chown mysql:mysql region.frm
chown mysql:mysql region.MYD
chown mysql:mysql region.MYI
```

STEP 04

Convert the Table to InnoDB

```
mysql> use mydb
mysql> ALTER TABLE region ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

That's it.

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Answer (score 3):

You are migrating from 5.0 to 5.7, so the safest way is to dump and restore using mysqldump, you can find this link useful http://mysqlserverteam.com/upgrading-directly-from-mysql-5-0-to-5-7-with-mysqldump/

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  Yes, I got it to work with your help.  Thanks!